# How to make View.onDraw synchronous

Tags: android, android-custom-view, synchronous, ondraw

I am writing an custom view where values are drawn through a method callback. Since callback timing is so small around 8ms and because of same drawing started to get shiver.

Is there any way to make `View.onDraw` synchronous.

Comment: synchronous? with what?

Comment: it's with drawing...so can draw callback values in sequence.

Comment: what actually do you want to do?

Comment: it's simple...I am doing some calculation in onDraw with callback values..but before to draw it new callback values occur..n drawing seq. get disturb.

Comment: What u not getting here..it's simple just wanted to Synchronization in drawing values coming from callback...any suggestion.

Comment: I'm afraid that with such level of clarity you will not get any answer...

Comment: Thanks for you confirmation dear :)

Comment: no problem,  next time try to be more clear  and specific, otherwise nobody will answer you

Comment: You already gave your suggestion...thanks again